# Creating multi column legend in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following script, which suppose
to create a plot with two column legend.

```
 #!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

file <- "http://dpaste.com/1354089/plain/";
dat <-read.table(file,header=TRUE);
datm <- melt(dat)

# Plot them
ggplot(datm,aes(x = variable,y = value,fill = Term)) +
geom_bar(position = "fill") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "bottom")+

guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))+ # this doesn't seem to work

ggsave(file="~/Desktop/test.pdf",width=11,height=11)
```

But it creates this figure instead
[image]

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

you must assign the guide to the correct aesthetic and you used fill:

```
guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

And you should take care of the warning with `geom_bar`

Comment: +1 for succinct answer. Any suggestion, how to address the warning?